# Line intersecting algorithm to return false when the end points are exactly in the same place?

Tags: java, math, geometry

I did not write this algorithm, but I am using it in my project. Whenever the two end points of the lines are exactly in the same place, this returns true. However, this is not desired. I would like for this to return false when two end points are at the exact same location, but even just a little past should return true.

[image]

```
private boolean doLineSegmentsIntersect(Point p, Point p2, Point q, Point q2) {

    //Used to calculate intersecting lines

    Point r = subtractPoints(p2, p);
    Point s = subtractPoints(q2, q);

    float uNumerator = crossProduct(subtractPoints(q, p), r);
    float denominator = crossProduct(r, s);

    if (denominator == 0) {
        //Lines are parallel
        return false;
    }

    float u = uNumerator / denominator;
    float t = crossProduct(subtractPoints(q, p), s) / denominator;

    return (t >= 0) && (t <= 1) && (u > 0) && (u <= 1);

}

private float crossProduct(Point point1, Point point2) {
    return point1.x * point2.y - point1.y * point2.x;
}

private Point subtractPoints(Point point1, Point point2) {
    Point result = new Point();
    result.x = point1.x - point2.x;
    result.y = point1.y - point2.y;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: A naive way is to also check that none the points are the same: (p.x == q.x && p.y == q.y) || (p2.x == q.x && p2.y == q.y) || (p.x == q2.x && p.y == q2.y) || (p2.x == q2.x && p2.y == q2.y)

Comment: `if p == q || p == q2 || p2 == q || p2 == q2 return false`. I think this should work.

Comment: Can't OP just use [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) from `Point`?

Comment: Don't use float. Use double instead; you will get much more accurate results.

Comment: @Andonaeus Yes, thank you for the idea. I've added this conditional statement to the first line. It will return false if any of the points meet up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider only open intervals when you `return` :

```
return (t > 0) && (t < 1) && (u > 0) && (u < 1);
```

This should take care of the case as in your illustration **but** will also return false if in your illustration you extend the horizontal line to the "right".
If this is not the behavior you are looking for, then the condition should be that either `t` is in the closed interval or `u` is in the closed interval but not both.

Comment: Yes. exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: NP, note that I tweaked my answer a bit.